# DateTimePicker behaves differently in XP and Windows Server 2008 when MaxDate is set?

Tags: winforms, datetimepicker

I'm using DateTimePicker in my winform application. The DateTimePicker allows a user to select a date that is not larger than DateTime.Now. I did this by set the controls MaxDate to DateTime.Now.

It works fine in XP, the dates that are larger than DateTime.Now are displayed, and user can not select them. But in Windows Server 2008, these dates are not displayed at all.

Is this an expected behavior or a microsoft bug?

XP
[image]
Windows Server 2008[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native Windows month calendar control got a pretty major overhaul at Vista, also the underlying code base for Windows 2008.  That affected the DateTimePicker and MonthCalendar classes, they are pretty simple .NET wrappers around the native Windows provided code.  Lots of Winforms classes are like this.

This is otherwise considered a nicety, your UI automagically adapts itself to the look-and-feel of the new operating system and the way other programs behave on it without you having to do anything at all.  Not displaying dates that you've made unselectable does arguably make an enormous amount of sense.  There is otherwise not anything you can do to change the way that native Windows code behaves, those wrappers are very thin.  Mostly because the native Windows controls don't have a lot of knobs.

Feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the .NET controls depend on the underlying operating system.  If the underlying control that Windows uses to represent a date-time chooser is different, then the one that shows up in your Winforms application will be different.

You can see that the controls are influenced by the operating system easily enough just on XP.  Change your theme from the standard "cartoony" theme that is the default to Windows Classic and run your .NET apps.  The form borders will go from haing the rounded corners and cartoony interface to having the classic format.

The date-time chooser that Windows uses by default is in the MScomctl.ocx.

If this changed between versions of Windows (which I'm sure it did) then your windorms will look and/or behave differently accordingly.